# Issue with Application View Koudoku and Instance Variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have created a contact form in the footer of the page and hence it's been placed within the application layout. I have also set up Koudoku to manage my stripe payments on the site.

Via the [Koudoku documentation](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku) it says since Koudoku uses the application layout all paths must be prefixed with `main_app.`

This has been implemented for all the links already, however the contact form is using a instance variable declared in the application controller like this.

```
def set_contact
  @contact = Contact.new
end
```

and the form in the application view looks like this

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :comments %>
     <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

I am getting this error here

```
undefined method `contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8b4d6bb658>:0x007f8b5033fc88>
```

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: Routes file is simply set up as ``resources :contacts``

Comment: In which view file you put your form?

Comment: Inside my layouts/application_view

Comment: Do you have `before_action :set_contact` in the `ApplicationController`?